# Removing empty words from column of tokenized sentences

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe containing lists of words in each row in the same column. I'd like to remove what I guess are spaces. I managed to get rid of some by doing:

```
for i in processed.text:
    for x in i:
        if x == '' or x==" ":
            i.remove(x)
```

But some of them still remain.

```
>processed['text']

0         [have, month, #postdoc, within, on, chemical, ...
1         [hardworking, producers, iowa, so, for, state,...
2         [hardworking, producers, iowa, so, for, state,...
3         [today, time, is, to, sources, energy, much, p...
4         [thanks, gaetanos, club, c, oh, choosing, #rec...
                                ...                        
130736    [gw, fossil, renewable, import, , , , , , , , ...
130737                                     [s, not, , go, ]
130738                        [answer, deforestation, in, ]
130739    [plastic, regrind, any, and, grades, we, make,...
130740                     [grid, generating, of, , , , gw]
Name: text, Length: 130741, dtype: object

>type(processed)
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Split on comma remove empty values and then combine again with comma

```
def remove_empty(x):
    if type(x) is str:
        x = x.split(",")
        x = [ y for y in x if y.strip()]
        return ",".join(x)
    elif type(x) is list:
        return [ y for y in x if y.strip()]

processed['text'] = processed['text'].apply(remove_empty)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Sadly, this code returns an error: ```Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\placi\PycharmProjects\TweetPerTopic\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 4108, in apply
    mapped = lib.map_infer(values, f, convert=convert_dtype)
  File "pandas\_libs\lib.pyx", line 2467, in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer
  File "<input>", line 44, in remove_empty
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'```

Answer (score 0):

You can use split(expand=True) to do that. Note: You dont have to specifically give spilt(' ', expand=True). By default, it takes ' ' as the value. You can replace `' '` with anything. For ex: if your words separate with `,` or `-`, then you can use that separator to split the columns.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Col1':['This is a long sentence',
                           'This is another long sentence',
                           'This is short',
                           'This is medium  length',
                           'Wow. Tiny',
                           'Petite',
                           'Ok']})

print (df)
df = df.Col1.str.split(' ',expand=True)
print (df)
```

The output of this will be:

Original dataframe:

```
                            Col1
0        This is a long sentence
1  This is another long sentence
2                  This is short
3         This is medium  length
4                      Wow. Tiny
5                         Petite
6                             Ok
```

Dataframe split into columns

```
        0     1        2     3         4
0    This    is        a  long  sentence
1    This    is  another  long  sentence
2    This    is    short  None      None
3    This    is   medium          length
4    Wow.  Tiny     None  None      None
5  Petite  None     None  None      None
6      Ok  None     None  None      None
```

If you want to limit them to 3 columns only, then use n=2

```
df = df.Col1.str.split(' ',n = 2, expand=True)
```

The output will be:

```
        0     1                      2
0    This    is        a long sentence
1    This    is  another long sentence
2    This    is                  short
3    This    is         medium  length
4    Wow.  Tiny                   None
5  Petite  None                   None
6      Ok  None                   None
```

If you want to rename the columns to be more specific, then you can add rename to the end like this.

```
df = df.Col1.str.split(' ',n = 2, expand=True).rename({0:'A',1:'B',2:'C'},axis=1)

        A     B                      C
0    This    is        a long sentence
1    This    is  another long sentence
2    This    is                  short
3    This    is         medium  length
4    Wow.  Tiny                   None
5  Petite  None                   None
6      Ok  None                   None
```

In case you want to replace all the `None` with `''` and also prefix the column names, you can do it as follws:

```
df = df.Col1.str.split(expand=True).add_prefix('Col').fillna('')

     Col0  Col1     Col2    Col3      Col4
0    This    is        a    long  sentence
1    This    is  another    long  sentence
2    This    is    short                  
3    This    is   medium  length          
4    Wow.  Tiny                           
5  Petite                                 
6      Ok
```